# How to get data which falls on specific days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time, where-clause

Hi I've start_date column which capture time stamp, I'd like to query the data based on days like if date falls on  sunday or monday like that.

For example

```
from_date = Tue Nov 22 23:00:00 UTC 2016
to_date = Sun Nov 27 02:00:00 UTC 2016
```

Here I need get all the records  from tuesday 23:00 pm to sunday 02:00 am.

Comment: In your example you need all records which fall on sunday or monday between the dates from_date and to_date??

Comment: ummm, not exactly, sunday or monday I just give it for example.., In simple I need a records for every week from tuesday 23:00pm to sunday 02:00 am..., from_date and to_date or not constant it's a dynamic value.

Comment: you do not care the year and the month?

Comment: No, Year,  month and date and all not required...,

Comment: try with some like `TIME(start_date)  BETWEEN '?' AND '?'`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand if possible give me some example..., and I guess If I try like that way consider start_date is Wed nov 22 05:00:00 UTC 2014, here you could see the day is Wednesday 5am do you think the above query will bring the record?

Comment: I think you can try with some like `Model.where(" start_date < '?' AND start_date > '?' AND TIME(start_date) BETWEEN '?' AND '?'", to_date , from_date , "23:00:00" ,"02:00:00")` [mysql TIME function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html)

Answer (score 1):

### Updated Answer

MySQL has [`dayofweek` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) for this.

You can write your query as:

```
MyModel.where('dayofweek(start_date) = ?', 1) # 1 is Sunday
```

To get all models which start_date is on Sunday.

To achieve your goal, you can query **start_date on Tuesday AND start_date hour is later than 23:00**, **start_date on Wed**, **start_date on Thurs** and etc.

So the final query would be like:

```
MyModel.where('(dayofweek(start_date) = ? AND hour(start_date) > ?) 
OR dayofweek(start_date) = ? OR dayofweek(start_date) = ? OR
dayofweek(start_date) = ? OR dayofweek(start_date) = ? OR
(dayofweek(start_date) = ? AND hour(start_date) > ?)'
, 3, 23, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2)
```

### Previous Answer

You can use a range query with `where`:

```
Model.where(start_date: from_date..to_date)
```

Comment: but it will fetch nov 22nd to nov 27, I don't want for the specific date I need it based on day like from all Tuesday 23:00pm to sunday 2:00.

Comment: Hmm didn't read the question clearly. Which DB are you using, it may be DB dependent because rails query interface does not have this function.

Comment: am using mysql database

Comment: @sakthivel this query is based on day of week instead of specific date.